# How extract from openssl_decrypt text and secret key ? - PHP

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I'm trying to encrypt a word with a `key` and i found out `openssl_encrypt`.

Now (maybe) i'm able to do it but i can't to extract from it initial **word** and secret key.

```
 $text = "message";
 $method = "aes-128-gcm";
 $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
 $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
 $secretKey= "god";


if (in_array($method, openssl_get_cipher_methods())){       
  $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($text, $method, $secretKey, $options=0, $iv);
  $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $secretKey, $options=0, $iv);

  print_r($encrypted);

  print_r($decrypted);  
}
```

Besides when decryption is correct output is FALSE or TRUE ?

Comment: Why are you only echoing the decrypted string if it fails? Also double equals is bad practice. If $decrypted is an empty string or zero that would also equate to false

Comment: Also your openssl_decrypt will always fail due to your typo "secretKeyy"

Comment: @Shardj i edit post but nothing is change

Comment: You should be able to extract the initial word. Can you give an example of a secret key? Share it using the conversion of [bin2hex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using gcm, change $method to "aes-128-cbc"

Comment: now i tried rc4-hmac-md5 and works... but how can i understand which is best method ?

Comment: and how can i extract also the key ?

Comment: Sorry, your english is a little hard to understand. I tested it myself so I know your code works if you just change the $method to cbc. I don't know what you mean by extract the key. Use whatever method you like. Aes is good.